# Javascript, views and events best practice

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, events, view

I am creating a page which can play a video file with alternate plug-ins based on users selection. The URL encodes which video should be played.

The page is retrieved from a PHP server script. The user selects the plug-in by clicking on some AJAX links. Each link retrieves from server the required plug-in by doing an AJAX request with a Javascript function. This function must take as a parameter the video ID. On the client side I am using jQuery Javascript framework.

I would like to know which is the best practice for doing this as a design pattern. I am thinking at several alternatives:

1. use `onclick` HTML attribute for the AJAX links to call the functions that retrieve content from server
2. use jQuery `$(#element).click()` to map the Javascript function which retrieves content.

If I use the first alternative a can easily pass the video ID to the Javascript function:

```
<a id="X" href="#" onclick="retrieveXPlugin('<?php echo $id ?>')">X Plugin</a>
```

but the view code is mashed with events code, which is not a good practice.

The second alternative looks better, but I must bind the click event in the same PHP file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#X').click(function() { 
        retrieveXPlugin('<?php echo $id ?>'); 
    });
}
</script>
```

As I figure out I cannot include the above code in a separate .js file because I need the server side PHP variable `$id`. The only way to do this would be to use global Javascript variables which doesn't look so good.

So, which is the best practice to organize view and events in this example and in any other? I am waiting for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use, for exemple, the name attribute of your link:

```
<a id="X" href="#" name="<?php echo $id ?>">X Plugin</a>
```

And in a separate .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#X').click(function() { 
        retrieveXPlugin($(this).attr ('name')); 
    });
}
```

Or event better, like said in the comment below, is the [data-*](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attribute (thanks Raynos), so you could do that this way:

```
<a id="X" href="#" data-xplugin="<?php echo $id ?>">X Plugin</a>
```

And in a separate .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#X').click(function() { 
        retrieveXPlugin($(this).attr ('data-xplugin')); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Store it somewhere else. Not in the name. Maybe `data-XPLugin`

Comment: @Raynos can you explain further? data-XPLugin is not a valid html attribute as far as I know.

Comment: [it's valid HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/). The name attribute is used for server-side postbacks, and identifying elements. I believe putting this data in there is bad markup.

Comment: I don't think he can use `.data ('xplugin')` to _set_ the data, because need to echo the value. Maybe `.data ('xplugin')` can retrieve the information from the `data-xplugin` attribute ?

... if you want to contribute, you should not post mono-word comments ...

Comment: `.data(x)` is short for `.attr('data-'+x)` I was merely recommending you use `.data` to retrieve the data attribute rather then `.attr`

Comment: Interesting approach I didn't thought about storing data in attributes and also I knew nothing about data-* attributes. Thank you!

Comment: The problem with data-* attributes is that being from HTML5 specification are compatible with older browsers.

Comment: Yes it is HTML5, but there's no reason that it will break on older browser. Works on IE9 in IE7 mode (don't have a _real_ IE7). And if you don't like the use of `data-*`, I think that using the `name` attribute is still not a bad solution. And for the argument that the `name` attribute is used for server-side postbacks, an `<a>` link usually _don't_ do a postback.

Comment: In order to also have a more general answer regarding events assignment and to close this thread, I would like you to tell how do you generally assign events to HTML elements when using jQuery: 1. Using `onclick` HTML attribute; 2. Using `.click()` from jQuery in the same .html file; 3. Using `.click()` from jQuery in a separate .js file ?

Comment: Personnally I definitely preffer binding eventes using `.click()` in separate .js file, to have a clear separation between content and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply return the anchor + script tag like so:

```
<a id="X" href="#" onclick="retrieveXPlugin('<?php echo $id ?>')">X Plugin</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#X').click(function() { 
        retrieveXPlugin('<?php echo $id ?>'); 
    });
}
</script>
```

And this would bind the anchor to your player.